# \lofoot and \lefoot do not adjust correctly

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage, footer

When applying the comments \lofoot and \lefoot, the footer on the even page is not displayed. Furthermore the comment \headmark also contains the number of the chapter and I want only the name.

Does somebody has any idea?

Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
includemp,
                  showframe,
                  reversemp,
            paperwidth=20.1cm,
            paperheight=25.80cm,
            top=2.30cm,
            bottom=3.4cm,
            inner=2.7cm,
            outer=2.7cm,
            marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
            marginparsep=0.4cm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter          % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ 
}\thechapter\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}

% remove the vertical skip before the chapter heading
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp]{chapter}

\usepackage[footwidth=textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}


\begin{document}

\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark{chapter}
\lofoot{\makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}{\headmark}}
\lefoot{\makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}{test test 
 test}}

\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}



\chapter{chapter}
\thispagestyle{scrheadings}

\lipsum[2]
\section{section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[2]
\section{section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{subsection}
\lipsum[2]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the chapter number from the marks used in page header or footer redefine `chaptermarkformat`:

```
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}
```

By default `scrreprt` results in a onesided document. So there are only recto pages and `lehead` is not used. If the entry in the left footer should differ depending on even and odd page numbers you can use something like

```
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}%
  \ifodd \value{page}%
    \headmark
  \else
    test test test%
  \fi
}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage[
            includemp,
            showframe,
            reversemp,
            paperwidth=20.1cm,
            paperheight=25.80cm,
            top=2.30cm,
            bottom=3.4cm,
            inner=2.7cm,
            outer=2.7cm,
            marginparwidth=1.6cm, % Fixed for now
            marginparsep=0.4cm
            ]{geometry}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter          % to set the marginpar on the left side in showframe
\let\Gm@vrules@mpi\Gm@vrules@mpii
\makeatother

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ 
}\thechapter\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}%
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}
\renewcommand*{\subsubsectionformat}{\makebox[0pt][r]
{\thesubsubsection\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}}

% remove the vertical skip before the chapter heading
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-1sp plus -1sp minus 1sp]{chapter}

\usepackage[footwidth=textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}% activates pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\automark{chapter}
\ifoot{%
  \makebox[0pt][r]{\pagemark\autodot\hskip\marginparsep}%
  \ifodd \value{page}%
    \headmark
  \else
    test test test%
  \fi
}
\setkomafont{pageheadfoot}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}

\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{chapter}
\lipsum[2]
\section{section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{subsection}
\lipsum[2]

\lipsum[2]
\section{section}
\lipsum[2]
\subsection{subsection}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Assueming that you want to use pagestyle `scrheadings` for chapter pages too, I have redefined `\chapterpagestyle` to `scrheadings`.